# Derivation of Catalan numbers

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

Trying to go through the proof.

Let $C_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k C_{n-1-k}$ with $C_0 = 1$.

$$
G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n \\
G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k C_{n-1-k}) x^n \\
G(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k C_{n-1-k}) x^n \\
G(x) = 1 + x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k C_{n-1-k}) x^{n-1} \\
G(x) = 1 + x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} C_k C_{n-k}) x^n \\
$$
I got stuck here so I looked up the solution at this point and somehow they jump straight from the step I am on to: $G(x) = 1+x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n\right)^2$

How?

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia article on the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product); it’s basically just like ordinary polynomial multiplication.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So I suppose it's almost a "by-definition" thing: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n x^n$ times $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n x^n$ equals $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} C_k D_{n-k}) x^n$?

Comment: Yes; and if you write out a few terms and do an ordinary polynomial-style multiplication to get, say, the first four coefficients of the product series, you’ll see why it works that way. For instance, the only product that gives you a constant is $C_0D_0$. The products that give you an $x$ term are $C_0D_1x$ and $C_1xD_0$. and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the recurrence involves sum of products taken two at a time, it is somewhat natural to consider the expansion $(G(x))^2$.

Now what is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(G(x))^2$?

Even if you are not aware of the cauchy product rule, its is not hard to see that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(G(x))^2$ is $C_kC_0+C_{k-1}C_1 + \cdots + C_{0}C_{k}$

So, $(G(x))^2= C_1+C_2x+C_3x^2 ....=\frac{G(x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}$